# using <%= tag %>

Tags: asp.net

Hi guys i'am having problem using a property  in <%= %> tags.
The compiler for some reason would not pick up the properties inside the <%= %> tags. 
IDE being used is MVWD
The error i get is

```
Error   2   'ASP.webusercontrol1_ascx' does not contain a definition for  
'UserName' and no extension method 'UserName' accepting a first argument of type 
'ASP.webusercontrol1_ascx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an 
assembly reference?)    c:\Users\jonny\Documents\Visual Studio    2010\Projects\WebApplication8\WebApplication8\WebUserControl1.ascx    2   36  WebApplication8
```

My WebUserControl1.ascx file

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebUserControl1.ascx.cs"   
    Inherits="WebApplication8.WebUserControl1" %>
<b>Information about </b> <%= this.UserName%> 
<br /><br />

<%= this.UserName %> is <%= this.UserAge %> years old and lives in <%= this.UserCountry %>
```

and here is my Webusercontrol1.ascx.cs file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication8
{
public partial class WebUserControl1 : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{

    private string userName;
    private int userAge;
    private string userCountry;

    public string UserName
    {
        get { return userName; }
        set { userName = value; }
    }

    public int UserAge
    {
        get { return userAge; }
        set { userAge = value; }
    }

    public string UserCountry
    {
        get { return userCountry; }
        set { userCountry = value; }
    }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }


 }
```

Comment: User controls should be in ASCX files.

Comment: Should work just fine. Might sound silly, but did you compile your code?

Comment: i'm using IDE its auto compiled, the error only comes when code is compiled.

Comment: Does your .designer.ascx.cs seem to match your .ascx.cs?

Comment: the designer class has nothing in it, its empty.

Comment: ...but it says the same `public partial class`...

Comment: ah yes it has the class deceleration, my bad didn't meant to say its completely empty.

Comment: You want to upload the relevant files (ascx, ascx.cs, ascx.designer.cs) to bitbucket?

Comment: here is the ascx file [link](http://pastebin.com/Gy5bhcsa)  ascx.cs  [link](http://pastebin.com/M88ceqHg) and ascx.designer.cs [link](http://pastebin.com/Df782L5c) i really appreciate your help

Comment: No repro, sorry! Even when you put it in a new project and build, you get this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can put the fields into literal controls, it's true the aspx will look ugly. something like this (I'm using for resources but should be simillar)

```
<asp:Literal ID="Literal6" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:General, lblFunctie %>"></asp:Literal>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to remove the "this." prefix...

Comment: There's something wrong with your codebehind or inherits statement then. Does your intellisense come work? Have you tried to rebuild your project?

Comment: The only other thing that stands out to me is in the error... "ASP.webusercontrol1_ascx" suggests there may be another namespace involved? ASP.?